# How to deploy Azure Web Apps using Azure Resource Manager-Based PowerShell?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager

I want to deploy my Azure web apps using PowerShell. Here is my expected workflow:

- Create Package using MSBuild
- Deploy the package to Azure

I tried with the approach described in the below link:
https://github.com/gregpakes/DoIHaveGPS/blob/master/PublishScripts/Publish-WebApplication.ps1

I modified the script to use an existing web app instead of creating. So I call something like Get-AzureWebsite -Name $Config.name..

But it never finds the existing app service (web app) due to the subscription issue. I tried so many times to switch the subscription but it's not working. Get-AzureWebsite always keep searching on the old subscription which I don't use anymore.

If I call Get-AzureRmSubscription from powershell I get two subscriptions but if I call Get-AzureSubscription I get only one.

How can I deploy my application packages using powershell using resource manager based powershell?

Answer (score 1):

The cmdlets used by the script you linked to are using the "old" service management interface.  If Get-AzureSubscription doesn't return a subscription that means it's only available to use via AzureRM.  The AzureRM web app cmdlets don't have a simple "publish" command as the old ones did... So if you wanted to replicate that in PowerShell you could do something like this:

```
$deploycmd = "$env:ProgramFiles\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe"

$packageLocation = Resolve-Path -Path "C:\users\bjm\downloads\package.zip"

$webAppName = 'myazuresite'
$user = '$myazuresite'
$pass = 'jSjku1lWBdZNgGjyZWYfDhFn4DFfZlAqTq1RjPu5Fnv3yYe9l2Fl5xz5RK0x'
$setParam =  "-setParam:name=""IIS Web Application Name"",value=$webAppName"
$dest = "-dest:auto,ComputerName='https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=$webAppName',UserName='$user',Password='$pass',AuthType=Basic"

& $deploycmd "-verb:sync", "-source:package=$packageLocation", $setParam, $dest
```

I actually prefer juvchan's approach but if you've already got the rest in place via PS this might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

After you've created the web deploy package for your application, you need to create a Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template which allows you to deploy to a Azure web app using the web deploy package.

Then you can use the Azure PowerShell cmdlet below to deploy your ARM template above to achieve what you require.

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -Name <deployment-name> -ResourceGroupName <resource-group-name> -TemplateUri <ArmTemplateJsonUri>
```

Useful references:

[Deploy a web app with MSDeploy, custom hostname and SSL certificate](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/app-service-web/app-service-web-arm-with-msdeploy-provision.md)

[Deploy your app to Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-deploy#a-nameoverviewaazure-app-service-deployment-overview)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-cli.md
https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy-cli.md

This topic shows how to use the Azure portal with Azure Resource Manager to deploy your Azure resources. To learn about managing your resources, see Manage Azure resources through portal. Currently, not every service supports the portal or Resource Manager. For those services, you need to use the classic portal. For the status of each service, see Azure portal availability chart.
1. To create an empty resource group, select New > Management > Resource Group.
2. Give it a name and location, and, if necessary, select a subscription. You need to provide a location for the